# Any published link on our facebook page redirects to the main domain only

Tags: facebook

We are experiencing a strange behavior on facebook and are stuck what the reason could be.

When we share a link on our facebook page that links to an article on our site, the first time somebody clicks on it, facebook redirects it to the main domain instead of the article.

The second time clicking on the same link behaves correctly and redirects it to the given article.  I can see that facebook does some tracking everytime the link is clicked, but I don't understand why it causes the link to fail the first time.

**Example:**
https://www.facebook.com/WatchFit

First timeline story with the title: 
**20 minutes wonder workout** that includes a link to the article: 
http://www.watchfit.com/article/Watchfit-Weekly-Workout-Challenge/142

The first time you click on it, it goes to http://www.watchfit.com instead of the given article. The second time clicking goes to the given article.

Is this a bad setting on facebook developer settings? Or what could cause this please?

Comment: It seems to be a problem in your site. Through the facebook it worked. But clicking in the link in your post it redirected to the main domain.

Comment: Thanks for comment. May you elaborate what you mean "through the facebook it worked"? Because now if you clicked the link in the post again, it would actually work the second time.  And thats what confuses me.

Comment: I clicked on the link in your facebook. And, at first time, it worked.

But when i clickedon the link which you posted here on Stackover, i was redirected to the main domain. So, the problem is not on facebook.

Comment: you are right. I was just able to replicate it. :( thanks